# htaccess help needed

Tags: .htaccess

I need a htaccess , which will do the following logic:

http://sitename.com/app   will go to http://sitename.com/app/index.php

http://sitename.com/app   will go to  http://sitename.com/app/index.php

http://sitename.com/app/a/b/c   will go to http://sitename.com/app/index.php/a/b/c

http://d.sitename.com/app    will go to http://sitename.com/app/index.php/shop/index/d

http://d.sitename.com/app/a/b/c    will go to    http://sitename.com/app/index.php/a/b/c/d

Is there any help possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this site](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml) for help and examples. Looks like it covers what you are asking (or am I misunderstanding your question?).